# Ubuntu Hyper-V VM Production Checkpoints Suddenly Failing

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v

I have an Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS VM that all the suddenly started failing to create "Production Checkpoints" which "Use backup technology in the guest operating system to create data-consistent checkpoints that don't include information about running applications." So the guest os, Ubuntu, is directly involved in the process. When Ubuntu is running, these checkpoints do not work, but "Standard Checkpoints" which do not interact with the guest os do work. When the os is shutdown, either checkpoint works. I think this is because there is no running OS to interact with and so a Production Checkpoint against a shutdown os is effectively Standard.

Production Checkpoints on this virtual host are working with other VMs, 2 of which are also Ubuntu so its not a general error at the host level.

I have done the following.

- Made sure the VM is completely up-to-date.
- Rebooted the VM multiple times.
- Made sure the linux vm integration tools are installed with

  ```
  apt-get install --install-recommends linux-virtual-lts-xenial
  ```
- Rebooted the Virtual Host
- Made sure the Virtual Host is up-to-date.

Reiterating, I am trying to fix issues with "Production Checkpoints" that require interaction from the guest os, not just general Checkpoints.

Comment: Checkpoints are created on the windows side not by Ubuntu , ie there are no tools in Ubuntu to create a Hyper-V checkpoint. I suggest you contact Microsoft. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/checkpoints

Comment: I get what you are saying somewhat except that the Production Checkpoint system is working as intended for literally every other VM except this one and it works for this one when the VM is turned off, when Ubuntu is not active production snapshots work, when it is active, production snapshots don't work. And the OS "IS" somewhat involved in the process since you have to have the linux intigration services installed/supported in the Ubuntu os for full VM functionality. So snapshots don't happen completely free of the guest. Production snapshots in particular specificially state

Comment: ... "Uses backup technology in the guest operating system to create data-consistent checkpoints" so the guest os, Ubuntu, IS involved in the process when running Production Checkpoints.

Comment: What differences exist between the VM that fails and those that function? File system? Configuration? Are we trying to save a checkpoint to a location that doesn't exist or that we don't have permission to write to? what "backup technology in the guest operating system" are you attempting to use in all cases? (both failed and successful)

Comment: @ElderGeek - Very little, in my opinion, is different. They use the same OS version, they are all up-to-date. The only real difference is in the user facing apps they are hosting(and any packages required by app). The server that is suddenly having trouble is hosting an instance of Team Password Manager (https://teampasswordmanager.com/), so it has that and packages required for it and is otherwise a fairly plain Ubuntu server install.  Samples of other Ubuntu server installs that are working are a WatchGuard Dimension server(admittedly that is a prepackaged vhd from the company so I can't...

Comment: ...say too much of its build, and a vm running the dockerized version of Xibo(https://xibo.org.uk/).  I don't think it has to do with checkpoint file permissions, as I said, non-production checkpoints work fine and they are stored in the same place as production checkpoints. So far as backup technologies inside the Os, that is part of why I'm here. But that said, I suspect its a combination of Ubuntu's built-in backup tool(haven't been able to find what package(s) this is to try and re-install it) and the linux integration services module(which I have tried re-installing on the vm).

Comment: @Kaz Interesting, but since I swore off Microsoft products unless absolutely necessary years ago I personally can't help you. Have you tried [this suggestion?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040277/ubuntu-hyper-v-vm-production-checkpoints-suddenly-failing?noredirect=1#comment1694297_1040277) Reviewed all the settings for the VM's and insured that they are identical?